# Is this an attack

Tags: webserver, databases

Original site: ---topbargains-com-au

A fake replica: --topbargain-org

How dangerous is this? Have they copied the whole database?

Edit: Removed the URLs to satisfy a spam allegation

Edit: The fake replica site contains this line in the footer.

```
src="http://js.tongji.linezing.com/3598203/tongji.js
```

Edit: See below comments, it seems like a masking attempt. Still no idea how to report them?

Comment: Nice spam attempt as both domains are registered in June.

Comment: God, I hope you are just having a bad day else you would have noted that first site is 10 year old domain.

Comment: I have removed the links to counter your unfounded suspicion. Can you help with the issue now?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Are you saying that the replica site is a full copy of the original website? What do you want to report them for?

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of a **phishing attack**? A phishing attack involves tricking a user into entering credentials into a website that looks much like a legitimate one.

For example, suppose First World Bank has the domain name of *firstworldbank.com*. Eve, the attacker, might create *firstw0rldbank.com* or *flrstworldbank.com*. She then sends an email to Bob that claims his passsword needs to be renewed, with a link to one of the fake websites. If Bob falls for the trick and logs in, he loses his credentials.

I seriously doubt this is a phishing attempt, however! <strike>A cursory glance at both websites shows that they have significantly different layouts and content. It's much more likely that two different people decided that "top bargain" is a good name for a coupon-related service.</strike>

They are the same website, or, at least, appear to be so. The .org domain contains a traffic-monitoring script, but otherwise appears to be the same. They also resolve to different IP addresses. I'm not a web guru, so I can't say if this is suspicious or not.

As a precaution, though, you *may* want to query the customer support of the .com.au domain. I'm certain they'll let you know if the other site is legitimate or not.

Comment: No the layout is same - you are seeing different content due to caching. Upon further research, it seems they are just masking the domain and including a script for malicious purposes. No server has been breached for sure.

Comment: Another attempt they made at masking another coupon website (HOTUKDEALS) https://www.virustotal.com/en/domain/hotvouchercodes.org/information/

Comment: Oh, I see. I jumped to a different page on the .org site than on the .com.au site, so it looked different. Updating my answer now.

Comment: Thanks mate .. I work for the .com.au site and know for sure that other site is not authorized.

Comment: Ahh, you should have said that sooner! In that case, they're probably redirecting to your site and appending a traffic monitoring script to see how many people are going through the domain. I might dig through it this evening and see what's up.

Comment: thanks - from a quick google search, that script is actually a virus.

Comment: Eek, you're right! I googled the script's name, but misspelled it, so nothing came up. Good catch there. This is quite an old attack, so I dunno if it's still effective against modern patched systems. Regardless, it definitely makes this website malicious.